# how to make image move smoothly with C#

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to make a game like Chain Reaction (http://www.yvoschaap.com/chainrxn/)with C#/winform, but i can't find a way to make image move smoothly just like the effect in Chain Reaction .anyone can give me some ideas?

Comment: yeah, don't use winforms

Comment: you can use XNA framework for game creation

Comment: is your problem that it isnt moving from a to b smoothly or it isnt turning from a ball to an explosion very smoothly?

Comment: Look into XNA Game Studio: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

Comment: i tried double buffer and timer+changing the coordinate, but still have flicker, not as good as the Chain Reaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common issue when implementing any kind of custom drawing in WinForms, be it a game, a graph, or any owner-drawn control. The issue is that by default all WinForms controls have the DoubleBuffer property set to False.

Setting the Form's DoubleBuffer property to True will get rid of that annoying flicker.

XNA is a good choice for game development, as suggested in the comments, but for a quick fix in WinForms all you probably need to do is set the Form to paint with a [double buffer](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying to make this game with MFC~

Comment: In the original post you mention wanting to make the game with C# and WinForms. MFC is a big difference. In any case, take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion any way. WinForm is my first choice , but lot people told me MFC is better for this game.The game is almost finished with MFC.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I had to make something move in c# I used timers.
Every tick you increase/decrease the image position withlike this :

`image.Left += 1;`

If I remember right it was doing the job just fine, but I'm not sure it will be easy to implement.

I hope it helps anyway ! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your form constructor add this lines:

```
SetStyle( ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true );
SetStyle( ControlStyles.UserPaint, true );
SetStyle( ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true );   
SetStyle( ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true );
```

This will help to optimize redering.

For your movement your should use a timer that Invalidate the control at a fixed rate of time... and you have to keep calcs in a floating point struct like PointF to avoid flicker in movements...

```
// This will move 30 pixels per second it rate is the elapsed time in seconds between calls to the update position method, and should move smooth :)
PointF Velocity = (30,0) * time_rate;  
PointF Pos = Pos + Velocity;
```

and you should use only a control that will be your screen game, maybe a PictureBox, in the paint method you can draw the balls this way:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;

   foreach (Ball ball in balls)
   {
       ball.Update();
       g.FillEllipse(ball.Brush, ball.Pos.X - ball.Radius, ball.Pos.Y - ball.Radius, ball.Radius*2, ball.Radius*2);
   }
}
```